# How Do You "dotnet lambda package-ci" for arm64?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, arm

#### Describe the issue

We are trying to use `dotnet lambda package-ci` to package for arm64

`dotnet lambda package --help` documentation shows `-farch | --function-architecture        The architecture of the Lambda function. Valid values: x86_64 or arm64. Default is x86_64`

Yet, `dotnet lambda package-ci --help` shows no switch for architecture.

We have issued:

1. `dotnet lambda package-ci ... --runtime linux-arm64`
2. `dotnet lambda package-ci  ... --function-architecture arm64 --msbuild-parameters "--arch linux-arm64"`
3. `dotnet lambda package-ci ... --function-architecture arm64`

These do not produce any arm64 results, all produce the publish command as something like `dotnet publish --output "/codebuild/output/src054284391/src/bbapi/WebApi/./bin/Release/net6.0/publish" --configuration "Release" --framework "net6.0" /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained false` or an error

So, how Do You "dotnet lambda package-ci" for arm64?

#### Links

https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The architecture comes from whatever is specified in your temlate file when you specify the architecture for the AWS::Serverless::Function.

[Taken from the GitHub repo:](https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli)

###### Package CI

```
dotnet lambda package-ci
```

Used for serverless applications. It creates the Lambda application bundle and uploads it to Amazon S3. It then writes
a new version of the serverless.template with the location of the Lambda function code updated to
where the application bundle was uploaded. In an AWS CodePipeline this command can be executed as part of a **CodeBuild**
stage returning the transformed template as the build artifact. Later in the pipeline that transformed serverless.template can
be used with a CloudFormation stage to deploy the application.

###### Notes

`dotnet lambda package-ci` inspects and uses the [`Architectures` property of `AWS::Serverless::Function`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-architectures) to determine the runtime of the package.

For example:

```
      "Architectures": [
        "arm64"
      ],
```

will execute `dotnet publish` with a `--runtime` argument of value `linux-arm64`:

Comment: Ha!  I added that to the repo and opening a ticket and gleaning that info.  Clearly my submission was understandable.  Thanks